# Enterprise build for apple watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to create enterprise build for apple watch project by xcode 6.3

I tried to build by archive and by auto-build (shenzhen tool)

When I run it at iPhone, it crashes immediately but with ad-hoc build it's work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Xcode Automatic selections do not work properly for code signing and provisioning profile when used with Apple Watch; sometimes it makes the wrong choice and you only notice when it has problems installing and launching.

For each of the App, App Extension, and Watch App, select the code signing certificate and provisioning profile explicitly (not automatic) in the pop up list.

For issues upon launch on the device (from spring board) the device console gives good information.  Install iOS Console, from [lemonjar.com](http://lemonjar.com) to easily see such information.